# t-test but the ratio of datasets is not the same Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, correlation

I have two sets of data. Both of them are values of volume on intersection. One set is collected by floating cars, the second one is counted by an inductive loop. 
Both have the same trend, but I can prove it only by a figure. I need to make another analysis. I think, the t-test is the good choice, but values of volume collected by floating cars are only 2-3% compared to volumes counted by inductive loop. Any idea how to compare these two data sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis appears to be that the data from your floating cars and the counts from the inductive loop are *correlated*. MATLAB has a function `corr` for that. A large correlation coefficient may support your hypothesis. A corresponding p-value is also calculated and returned as the second argument:

```
>> a = [100; 150; 120; 140];
>> b = [1.9; 3.2; 2.2; 3.1];
>> [rho, pval] = corr([a,b])
rho =
    1.0000    0.9742
    0.9742    1.0000
pval =
    1.0000    0.0258
    0.0258    1.0000
```

A correlation coefficient of 0.97 is pretty strong. To test how rarely this would happen by chance with the given number of data points, you can look at the corresponding p-value. The p-value in this example, p=0.026, is rather small, supporting your hypothesis that the values are correlated. You can find a [detailed explanation here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient).

Comment: Thank you, I did it your way and it gives this result:

`rho =  
   1.000000000000000   0.670840082408877  <br/>
   0.670840082408876   1.000000000000000  <br/>
pval =  <br/>
   1.000000000000000   0.000000000000000  <br/>
   0.000000000000000   1.000000000000000`  <br/>
I´m suprised, that the pval=0. What does it mean?

Comment: What does `pval(1,2)` yield in your case? It may be that your p-value is many orders of magnitude smaller than one. Also, how many data points do you have?

Comment: `pval(1,2)=0.0000000`. As I've mentioned one data set is 2-3% values of the second one. Like `x(1,1)=17` and `y(1,1)=480`

Comment: The scaling of values does not matter. You could check the link in my answer to read up on this. If you have a large number of points, p-values can become very small. `xcorr` may be interesting for you if this is time series data.